# Get Average Precipitation of a City using the Wunderground API + PHP

Tags: php, json, wunderground

I am currently trying to output to the user the probability of precipitation (POP) in their given city using the [Wunderground API](https://wunderground.com/weather/api/) and `PHP`. The Wunderground API returns its requests in JSON format. Yet I am currently getting nothing back and I don't know what the problem is.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
  $json_string =  file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/forecast/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
  $location = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'};
  $pop = $parsed_json->{'pop'};
  echo "Percipation: ${pop}%";
?>
```

I know that this task is accomplishable with Javascript, I eventually want it to interface to a MySQL database.

*** I didn't include my API Key because I have a limited number of API calls per day, and after that I start getting charged money :(.

EDIT 1:

**Below is the HTTP Response Header**

```
array(13) { 
    [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" 
    [1]=> string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes" 
    [2]=> string(29) "Cache-Control: max-age=604800" 
    [3]=> string(23) "Content-Type: text/html" 
    [4]=> string(35) "Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 20:55:54 GMT" 
    [5]=> string(17) "Etag: "359670651"" 
    [6]=> string(38) "Expires: Mon, 27 Feb 2017 20:55:54 GMT" 
    [7]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT" 
    [8]=> string(22) "Server: ECS (cpm/F9D5)" 
    [9]=> string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding" 
    [10]=> string(12) "X-Cache: HIT" 
    [11]=> string(20) "Content-Length: 1270" 
    [12]=> string(17) "Connection: close" 
}
```

EDIT 2:

**Below is the JSON return (Brace yourself)**

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "forecast": 1
  }
    }
        ,
    "forecast":{
        "txt_forecast": {
        "date":"1:04 PM CST",
        "forecastday": [
        {
        "period":0,
        "icon":"rain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif",
        "title":"Monday",
        "fcttext":"Cloudy with periods of rain. Thunder possible. High 61F. Winds S at 10 to 15 mph. Chance of rain 90%.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Rain. Thunder possible. High 16C. Winds S at 15 to 25 km/h. Chance of rain 90%.",
        "pop":"90"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":1,
        "icon":"nt_chancerain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_chancerain.gif",
        "title":"Monday Night",
        "fcttext":"Rain showers this evening with overcast skies overnight. Thunder possible. Low 39F. Winds W at 5 to 10 mph. Chance of rain 60%.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Showers early, then cloudy overnight. Thunder possible. Low 4C. Winds WSW at 10 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 60%.",
        "pop":"60"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":2,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Tuesday",
        "fcttext":"Some clouds in the morning will give way to mainly sunny skies for the afternoon. Near record high temperatures. High around 65F. Winds WSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Some clouds in the morning will give way to mainly sunny skies for the afternoon. Near record high temperatures. High 18C. Winds WSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":3,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Tuesday Night",
        "fcttext":"Clear skies. Low 39F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear skies. Low 4C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":4,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Wednesday",
        "fcttext":"Mostly sunny skies with gusty winds developing during the afternoon. High 71F. Winds SSW at 20 to 30 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mostly sunny skies. Becoming windy during the afternoon. High 21C. Winds SSW at 30 to 50 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":5,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Wednesday Night",
        "fcttext":"A mostly clear sky. Low 38F. Winds WNW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"A mostly clear sky. Low 3C. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":6,
        "icon":"chancerain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancerain.gif",
        "title":"Thursday",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy in the morning. Increasing clouds with periods of showers later in the day. High 54F. Winds NE at 15 to 25 mph. Chance of rain 80%.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy skies during the morning hours will give way to occasional showers in the afternoon. High 12C. Winds NE at 25 to 40 km/h. Chance of rain 90%.",
        "pop":"80"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":7,
        "icon":"nt_tstorms",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_tstorms.gif",
        "title":"Thursday Night",
        "fcttext":"Showers along with a few thunderstorms. Low 39F. Winds ENE at 20 to 30 mph. Chance of rain 100%.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Windy with showers and thunderstorms likely. Low 4C. Winds ENE at 30 to 50 km/h. Chance of rain 100%.",
        "pop":"100"
        }
        ]
        },
        "simpleforecast": {
        "forecastday": [
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1487638800",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM CST on February 20, 2017",
    "day":20,
    "month":2,
    "year":2017,
    "yday":50,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"0",
    "monthname":"February",
    "monthname_short":"Feb",
    "weekday_short":"Mon",
    "weekday":"Monday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"CST",
    "tz_long":"America/Chicago"
},
        "period":1,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"61",
        "celsius":"16"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"39",
        "celsius":"4"
        },
        "conditions":"Rain",
        "icon":"rain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":90,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.28,
        "mm": 7
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.27,
        "mm": 7
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.08,
        "mm": 2
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 15,
        "kph": 24,
        "dir": "S",
        "degrees": 169
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 12,
        "kph": 19,
        "dir": "S",
        "degrees": 169
        },
        "avehumidity": 84,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1487725200",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM CST on February 21, 2017",
    "day":21,
    "month":2,
    "year":2017,
    "yday":51,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"0",
    "monthname":"February",
    "monthname_short":"Feb",
    "weekday_short":"Tue",
    "weekday":"Tuesday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"CST",
    "tz_long":"America/Chicago"
},
        "period":2,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"65",
        "celsius":"18"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"39",
        "celsius":"4"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "WSW",
        "degrees": 238
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 9,
        "kph": 14,
        "dir": "WSW",
        "degrees": 238
        },
        "avehumidity": 63,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1487811600",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM CST on February 22, 2017",
    "day":22,
    "month":2,
    "year":2017,
    "yday":52,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"0",
    "monthname":"February",
    "monthname_short":"Feb",
    "weekday_short":"Wed",
    "weekday":"Wednesday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"CST",
    "tz_long":"America/Chicago"
},
        "period":3,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"71",
        "celsius":"22"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"38",
        "celsius":"3"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 30,
        "kph": 48,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 202
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 21,
        "kph": 34,
        "dir": "SSW",
        "degrees": 202
        },
        "avehumidity": 57,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1487898000",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM CST on February 23, 2017",
    "day":23,
    "month":2,
    "year":2017,
    "yday":53,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"0",
    "monthname":"February",
    "monthname_short":"Feb",
    "weekday_short":"Thu",
    "weekday":"Thursday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"CST",
    "tz_long":"America/Chicago"
},
        "period":4,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"54",
        "celsius":"12"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"39",
        "celsius":"4"
        },
        "conditions":"Chance of Rain",
        "icon":"chancerain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancerain.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":80,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.70,
        "mm": 18
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.07,
        "mm": 2
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.64,
        "mm": 16
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 25,
        "kph": 40,
        "dir": "NE",
        "degrees": 42
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 19,
        "kph": 31,
        "dir": "NE",
        "degrees": 42
        },
        "avehumidity": 72,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the response from the server including the HTTP headers. Have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php for help.

Comment: @0xJoKe - It was added... Do you want to take a look?

Comment: Thanks. Could you also add the contents of `$json_string` to you question? You do seem to get 1270 Bytes of content back. Do you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong variable in

```
$pop = $parsed_json->{'pop'};
```

Try it with

```
$pop = $location[0]->{'pop'};
```

**Be aware that `$location` should be an array**, so trying to directly access it (`$location->{'pop'}`) will not work. The `0` index serves only as an example.